# MATLAB crashes on Linux when trying to import Python module

Tags: python, linux, matlab

Every time I try to import a Python module from MATLAB (using `py.importlib.import_module`) it crashes. Sometimes the crash is immediate but other times it hangs for a while before crashing. Some modules seem to work, for example `py.importlib.import_module('math')` works fine, but `py.importlib.import_module('random')` causes a crash. I'm also unable to import custom modules.

This is the output of `pyversion`:

```
>> pyversion

       version: '3.7'
    executable: '/home/garden/anaconda3/bin/python3'
       library: '/home/garden/anaconda3/lib/libpython3.7m.so'
          home: '/home/garden/anaconda3'
      isloaded: 0
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

I'm not sure if this is helpful but I've narrowed it down to a particular line that's causing a crash, line 244 in the [hashlib](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/hashlib.py) module:

```
240 for __func_name in __always_supported:
241     # try them all, some may not work due to the OpenSSL
242     # version not supporting that algorithm.
243     try:
244         globals()[__func_name] = __get_hash(__func_name)
245    except ValueError:
246         import logging
247         logging.exception('code for hash %s was not found.', __func_name)
```

Comment: This looks like something that the MathWorks should be helping you with. Did you contact your representative?

Comment: I submitted a support ticket and posted a similar question on the MathWorks site as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per MathWorks support, this issue sometimes can arise when Python attempts to use the MathWorks version of `libcrypto`. This can be resolved by loading `SSL` using Python before attempting to import other modules. Adding these lines to the beginning of my MATLAB script seems to fix the problem for me:

```
py.sys.setdlopenflags(int32(10))
py.importlib.import_module('ssl')
```